# Why is this attempting to call the default constructor?

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor

In my original project I have a class whose constructor is supposed to call an initialization function before constructing a class member. However, the compiler is giving me an error for a missing default constructor for the class member.

```
class One
{
public:
    One(int i) {};
};

class Two
{
    One one;

public:
    Two() {one(0)};
};

int main(void)
{
    Two two;
}
```

The compiler gives me this:

```
Problem.cpp: In constructor ‘Two::Two()’:
Problem.cpp:12:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘One::One()’
         Two() {one(0)};
           ^
Problem.cpp:4:9: note: candidate: ‘One::One(int)’
         One(int i) {};
         ^~~
Problem.cpp:4:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Problem.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr One::One(const One&)’
 class One
       ^~~
Problem.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Problem.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr One::One(One&&)’
Problem.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Problem.cpp:12:21: error: no match for call to ‘(One) (int)’
         Two() {one(0)};
```

Why is this code attempting to call a default constructor for One in the Two constructor, and how can I produce the intended behavior (construct member after other initialization code in the constructor)?

Comment: This `Two two();` is not a constructor call, it's a function declaration. And you mean `Two() : one(0) {};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I produce the intended behavior (construct member after other initialization code in the constructor)?

This is not possible. In C++, all the object's base classes and non-static member variables must be constructed before the body of the constructor is entered.

In your code you wrote the opening `{` of the `Two` constructor without having previously offered any constructor arguments for the member variable, so the member variable is default-constructed.

---

If you have some logic to work out the initializer for `one` then I would recommend putting that into a function:

```
int f() { /* logic here */ return 0; }

// ...

Two(): one( f() ) {}
```

Of course you could also add a default constructor to `One` plus a means of assigning to it later.

Answer (score 2):

The default constructor is called because you don't call the one that takes an `int` as a parameter.  You have to do that in the initializer list :

```
class Two
{
    One one;

public:
    Two() : one(0) {}
};
```

You also need to declare your variable correctly :

```
Two two;
```

not

```
Two two();
```

---

By adding an init function and using the comma operator, you can get away with this:

```
class Two
{
    One one;

    void init()
    {
        // Initialize things here
    }

public:
    Two() : one((init(), 0)) {}
};
```

First, `init()` is called, then  `0` is passed to the `One` constructor.

Comment: I want to be able to initialize the member object inside the constructor body because it has to come after other initialization code.

Comment: That's just not possible.  You have to call the constructor in the initializer list.  But you can call a function from within the argument list.  See above.

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
class One
{
public:
    One(int i) {};
};

class Two
{
    One one;

public:
    Two() : one(0) {};
};

int main(void)
{
    Two two();
}
```

The reason it is calling the default constructor for `One` is that `Two::one` needs to be constructed before the first line of code in the `Two::Two` constructor, or else the `Two` hasn't really been constructed yet.  By placing the `One` constructor call in the initializer list, that ensures that the `One` gets the arguments that it needs to construct before any non-initializing `Two` code runs.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because all of `Two`'s members must be **fully** constructed before the `Two()` constructor's **body** is entered, but you are not explicitly constructing the `one` member in the `Two()` constructor's member initialization list, so the compiler attempts to default construct the `one` member for you, and fails since the `One` class does not have a default constructor.

To do what you are asking, you need to either:

- make `One` be default-constructible, and give it a way to be assigned a new value when needed:

  ```
  class One
  {
  private:
      int value;

  public:
      One(int i = 0) : value(i) {}

      One& operator=(int rhs)
      {
          value = rhs;
          return *this;
      }
  };

  class Two
  {
  private:
      One one; // <-- default constructed!

  public:
      Two()
      {
          // initialization as needed...
          one = 0; // <-- reassignment afterwards
      }
  };
  ```
- change the `one` member to be a `One*` pointer instead, and then you can construct it whenever you want, eg:

  ```
  class One
  {
  private:
      int value;

  public:
      One(int i = 0) : value(i) {}
      One(const One &src) : value(src.value) {}
  };

  class Two
  {
  private:
      One *one;

  public:
      Two() : one(NULL)
      {
          // initialization as needed...
          one = new One(0);
      }

      // don't forget about the "Rule of 3"...

      Two(const Two &src) : one(NULL)
      {
          // initialization as needed...
          one = new One(*(src.one));
      }

      ~Two()
      {
          delete one;
      }

      Two& operator=(const Two &rhs)
      {
          if (&rhs != this)
          {
              Two temp(rhs);
              std::swap(one, temp.one);
          }
          return *this;
      }
  };
  ```

  Or, if you are using C++11 or later:

  ```
  #include <memory>

  class Two
  {
  private:
      std::unique_ptr<One> one;

  public:
      Two()
      {
          // initialization as needed...
          one.reset(new One(0));
          // or: in C++14 and later:
          // one = std::make_unique<One>(0);
      }

      // don't forget about the "Rule of 3"...

      Two(const Two &src)
      {
          // initialization as needed...
          one.reset(new One(*(src.one)));
          // or: in C++14 and later:
          // one = std::make_unique<One>(*(src.one));
      }

      Two& operator=(const Two &rhs)
      {
          if (&rhs != this)
          {
              Two temp(rhs);
              std::swap(one, temp.one);
          }
          return *this;
      }

      // and the "Rule of 5"...

      Two(Two &&src)
      {
          // initialization as needed...
          one = std::move(src.one);
      }

      Two& operator=(Two &&rhs)
      {
          one = std::move(rhs.one);
          return *this;
      }
  };
  ```